# Rearrange Logcat buttons in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

For example, I want to swap these two buttons:

[image]

Is it possible? I'm using Android Studio 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create plugin which implement `"com.intellij.consoleActionsPostProcessor"` extension point.
According to the javadoc they can do what you want:

```
  /**
   * Allows to adjust actions to use within the given console instance.
   * <p/>
   * {@code 'Adjust'} here stands for 'add', 'remove', 'change order' etc.
   *
   * @param console     console instance which actions are being post-processed
   * @param actions     console actions that will be used by default
   * @return            actions to use within the given console instance (given actions may be returned by default)
   */
```

For further information see sources: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/actions/ConsoleActionsPostProcessor.java